# NAA flag has been sitting in the VLQ queue for 2 weeks (even though earlier and later flags have been reviewed)

Tags: support, not-an-answer

I recently flagged [this link-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666980/does-wikinvest-have-an-api/8811073#8811073) as NAA. While the OP is, in fact, looking for a library recommendation (which the links technically provided), the links are now dead. Obviously, this renders the answer completely useless (hence my NAA flag).

However, at this point, the post has been sitting in the VLQ queue for 2 weeks without being reviewed (even though some of my other earlier - and later - VLQ and NAA flags have been reviewed).

Any idea why this might be?

Comment: I've got an idea it'll be because it's accepted and therefore go to the mod queue, I don't think accepted answers can be deleted by anyone but a mod.

Comment: @PeterJ Wouldn't it make its way through the VLQ queue first, though, and then only go to the moderator queue if 4 people voted "recommend deletion"? I could be wrong, though.

Comment: I have an NAA flag that has been "pending" for over a month.

Comment: Look, an election! Please help us find more moderators to handle the flag load :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters meh, we rather take out the pitchforks and lash out to the sitting crew. Much more entertaining ... and no effort at all ...  ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"not an answer" flags can be handled at varying rates, depending on a number of factors that aren't obvious to the flagger. Flagged posts in the moderator queue are sorted first by number of flags on the post and then by the age of the flags. Posts that accumulate multiple flags jump to the top of the queue.

I checked, and the flags you had handled earlier than this one largely had multiple flags on them from other users. They also tended to be "have you solved this?" or "I like turtles" kinds of non-answers, which are easy to judge and delete in seconds from the queue.

Also, sometimes obvious flags can get buried between bad ones (people love flagging answers they simply don't like or think are wrong as "not an answer"), which can block us from seeing your flag until we work through those.

Community review can handle some of these, which further complicates when they might be processed.

And yes, there's an election going on right now to add more people to help.